# L144: TranslateModule.forRoot({ L145: provide: TranslateLoader, L146: useFactory: (createTranslateLoader),

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

İonic Cordova build Android Error ?

app.module.ts

https://www.paste.org/97841

https://pasteboard.co/I8ikkfl.png

```
        Argument of type '{ provide: typeof TranslateLoader; useFactory: any
```

; deps: (typeof HttpClient)[]; }' is not
            assignable to parameter of type 'TranslateModuleConfig'. Object lite
ral may only specify known properties,
            and 'provide' does not exist in type 'TranslateModuleConfig'.

```
 L144:  TranslateModule.forRoot({
 L145:      provide: TranslateLoader,
 L146:      useFactory: (createTranslateLoader),
```

[19:20:39]  typescript: C:/Users/ibret/Desktop/Mobile App Source/src/app/app.mod
ule.ts, line: 146
            Cannot find name 'createTranslateLoader'.

```
 L145:  provide: TranslateLoader,
 L146:  useFactory: (createTranslateLoader),
 L147:  deps: [HttpClient]
```

Comment: Could you imclude your code an any errors you get in the question itself and not as images. It makes it very hard for others to help you

Comment: @ChristopherMoore Corrected, sir

Comment: Did you solve it?